# Unable to access query string params inside AWS Api Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have configured a resource with a GET method on AWS API Gateway. Integration type is configured as HTTP, but it seems that I cannot access Url Query string parameters without Lambda Functions.

For example
I have api endpoint https://api.domain.com/v1/object/500?param_id=305 and I would like to integrate it with an existing http such as http://somedomain.com/object/500?param_id=305

When I define endpoint URL such as http://somedomain.com/object/{id}?param_id={param_id} I am not able to define param_id as url query string parameter
[image]

I am getting a following error:

```
Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression parameter specified: method.request.querystring.param_id
```

How can I access query string params without using Lambda functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use body mapping template in the integration request section and get request body and query strings. Construct a new JSON at body mapping template, which will have data from request body and query string. As we are adding body mapping template your business logic will get the JSON we have constructed at body mapping template.

Inside body mapping template to get query string please do ,

$input.params('querystringkey')

For example inside body mapping template,

```js
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
"firstName" : "$input.path('$.firstName')", //This is to get path variable
"lastName" : "$input.path('$.lastName')"
"language" : "$input.params('$.language')" //This is to get query string
}
```

Please read https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/tag/mapping-templates/ for more details on body mapping template

Comment: So for example #set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
"param_id": $input.params('param_id')
} would declare and set value for param_id variable and I can access it from  endpoint url  http://somedomain.com/object/{id}?param_id={param_id}. I just tried it and I get internal server error

Comment: After you setup it in body mapping template you can access it like normal JSON. For example in if you setup '#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
"param_id" : "$input.params('$.param_id')" //This is to get query string
}' in body mapping template then in Lambda you can say 'event.param_id'

Comment: My question was how to do it without Lambda

Comment: Lambda was just an example. As I have read from you question you are integrating to another API so that you can pass as a body to another API

Comment: For this particular case I am using HTTP integration type